# Error Unsupported Graphics card or driver. A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required. Blender 3.4 on Linux

Tags: drivers, linux

Attempting to run Blender 3.4.1 on Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.5LTS if I run via the terminal I see this:

Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.

Graphics card is AMD Radeon RX 5700XT running driver version 22.40. (downloaded today)

This happens only when running 3.4.1, exact same system, exact same setup, if I run Blender 3.3.1 it works fine, only 3.4.x (same on 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 was observed)

Comment: Might be worth reporting it as a bug since there's another posting here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282465/amd-radeon-rx-5700xt-not-recognized-as-hip