# AMD Radeon RX 5700XT not recognized as HIP

Tags: gpu, linux

Blender 3.3.1 says No compatible GPUs shown for cycles.
indicates requirements as AMD GPU, RDNA architecture, and driver version 22.10 or newer

System is Ubuntu 20.04.5LTS 64 bit, driver is AMD GPU 22.40. card is Radeon RX 5700XT. RX 5000 series is listed as compatible with cycles render on this page:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware

that page also says Linux: Radeon Software 22.10 or ROCm 5.3 is required.
I have a newer driver and ROCm version 5.4.1.50401-84~20.04.

Why is this card not being recognized and selectable for GPU rendering under HIP?

Comment: Might be worth reporting it as a bug since there's another posting here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282460/error-unsupported-graphics-card-or-driver-a-graphics-card-and-driver-with-suppo

Comment: You need to use the PRO Edition drivers

Comment: @JohnEason - sorry I suspect no. I'm playing with it and the problem seems to be is that I scaled everything down, while I created it probably the measurements were and remain the original. Weird, probably another bug.

Comment: @Bob what do you mean?

Comment: Also, after restart it started to show more sane numbers, still it's 3.010 vs 3.65